# Having issue getting data using ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<a on-swipe="onSwipe()" href="#/app/setting/{{book.id}}" ng-repeat="data in savedData">
```

I got my $scope.savedData from localstorage, how can I get {{book.id}} to know which item the user actually want to delete?

```
$scope.onSwipe = function () {
          //I need to get {{book.id}} here
};
```

bind it to a new ng-model?

Answer (score 1):

Pass it as a parameter:

```
<a on-swipe="onSwipe(book.id)" href="#/app/setting/{{book.id}}" ng-repeat="data in savedData">

$scope.onSwipe = function (id) {
      //id == book.id
};
```